# Can I change the caption on the save button of a TSavetextfiledialog in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I have a TSavetextfiledialog where the user selects a filename for saving, but the save doesn't happen immediately. Therefore I would like the save button to display "select" rather than "save". Can the caption of the button be changed?

[image]

Comment: Ooh, legacy XP dialog. I wouldn't use that. However, it's easy enough to enumerate the controls on an XP dialog. Look at the source code that adds the encoding drop down for a guide.

Comment: @David: What's so XP about it? It's a standard dialog from XE3. The title bar may look XP but that's the performance setting on my Win7 system.

Comment: @David: How do I enumerate the controls?

Comment: That's a legacy XP dialog because it uses the resource template mechanism to extend the dialog. Extension needed to add the drop down. As I said, look at the code that does that. You'll find the dialog window handle there. Dig out the button with EnumChildWindows or FindWindowEx.

Comment: Personally I'd use the Vista dialog, the native dialog, IFileDialog. That allows you to change the button text. And customise the dialog with a drop down, and not fall back to that legacy dialog.

Comment: @GeertGoeteyn - Since you're using XE3: In the Tool palette there's apart from the "normal" Dialogs palette also a Vista Dialogs palette.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is an old style common file open dialog, you can use `CDM_SETCONTROLTEXT` message on the item having `IDOK` identifier for the parent of the VCL's dialog handle. For IDs of other items, see documentation on [Explorer-Style Control Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Explorer_Style_Control_Identifiers). Here is calling it in the `OnShow` event handler:

```
uses
  commdlg;

procedure TForm2.SaveTextFileDialog1Show(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendMessage(GetParent(SaveTextFileDialog1.Handle),
      CDM_SETCONTROLTEXT, IDOK, NativeUInt(PChar('MyCaption')));
end;
```

The dialog is changing the button text when you select a folder to 'Open', when the selection is not a folder, your custom caption is restored.

Comment: I think this needs to execute when `OnSelectionChange` fires too

Comment: @David - When the selection is not a folder again, the custom caption is automatically restored. However you are right if the 'Open' needs to be customized too.

Comment: FTR, calling in OnSelectionChange does not prevent button text to become 'Open', presumably because button text has already been changed.

Comment: But it changes it back when you select a file

Comment: @David - Yes. It's more weird, it changes it back even when the focus is switched elsewhere.